# How to get time difference in specifc rows include in one column data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with time and three inputs. Here I calculate the time difference using panda.

code is :

```
data['Time_different'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['time'].astype(str)).diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

This is reading the difference of time in each row. But I want to write a code for find the time difference only specific rows which are having X3 values.

I tried to write the code using for loop. But it's not working properly. Without using for loop can we  write the code.?

[image]

As you can see in my image I have three inputs, X1,X2,X3. Here when I used that code it is showing the time difference of X1,X2,X3.

Here what I want to write is getting the time difference for X3 inputs which are having a values.

```html
time      X3

6:00:00  0
7:00:00  2
8:00:00  0
9:00:00  50
10:00:00 0
11:00:00 0
12:00:00 0
13:45:00 0
15:00:00 0
16:00:00 0
17:00:00 0
18:00:00 0
19:00:00 20
```

Then here I want to skip the time of having 0 values of X3 and want to read only time difference of values of X3.

```
time             x3

7:00:00          2(values having)
9:00:00          50
```

So the time difference is `2hrs`

Then second:

```
9:00:00          50
19:00:00         20
```

Then time difference is `10 hrs`

Like wise I want write the code or my whole column. Can anyone help me to solve this?

While putting the code then get the error with time difference in minus value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to:

- Find rows where `X3` different from 0
- Compute the difference is hours using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)
- Update the dataframe using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

Full example:

```
data = """time      X3
6:00:00     0
7:00:00     2
8:00:00     0
9:00:00     50
10:00:00    0
11:00:00    0
12:00:00    0
13:45:00    0
15:00:00    0
16:00:00    0
17:00:00    0
18:00:00    0
19:00:00    20"""
# Build dataframe from example
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s{1,}')
df['X1'] = np.random.randint(0,10,len(df))   # Add random values for "X1" column
df['X2'] = np.random.randint(0,10,len(df))   # Add random values for "X2" column

# Convert the time column to datetime object
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%H:%M:%S")
print(df)
#                   time  X3  X1  X2
# 0  1900-01-01 06:00:00   0   5   4
# 1  1900-01-01 07:00:00   2   7   1
# 2  1900-01-01 08:00:00   0   2   8
# 3  1900-01-01 09:00:00  50   1   0
# 4  1900-01-01 10:00:00   0   3   9
# 5  1900-01-01 11:00:00   0   8   4
# 6  1900-01-01 12:00:00   0   0   2
# 7  1900-01-01 13:45:00   0   5   0
# 8  1900-01-01 15:00:00   0   5   7
# 9  1900-01-01 16:00:00   0   0   8
# 10 1900-01-01 17:00:00   0   6   7
# 11 1900-01-01 18:00:00   0   1   5
# 12 1900-01-01 19:00:00  20   4   7

# Compute difference
sub_df = df[df.X3 != 0]
out_values = (sub_df.time.dt.hour - sub_df.shift().time.dt.hour) \
            .to_frame() \
            .fillna(sub_df.time.dt.hour.iloc[0]) \
            .rename(columns={'time': 'out'})  # Rename column
print(out_values)
#      out
# 1    7.0
# 3    2.0
# 12  10.0

df = df.join(out_values)                # Add out values
print(df)
#                   time  X3  X1  X2   out
# 0  1900-01-01 06:00:00   0   2   9   NaN
# 1  1900-01-01 07:00:00   2   7   4   7.0
# 2  1900-01-01 08:00:00   0   6   6   NaN
# 3  1900-01-01 09:00:00  50   9   1   2.0
# 4  1900-01-01 10:00:00   0   2   9   NaN
# 5  1900-01-01 11:00:00   0   5   3   NaN
# 6  1900-01-01 12:00:00   0   6   4   NaN
# 7  1900-01-01 13:45:00   0   9   3   NaN
# 8  1900-01-01 15:00:00   0   3   0   NaN
# 9  1900-01-01 16:00:00   0   1   8   NaN
# 10 1900-01-01 17:00:00   0   7   5   NaN
# 11 1900-01-01 18:00:00   0   6   7   NaN
# 12 1900-01-01 19:00:00  20   1   5  10.0
```

Here is use `.fillna(sub_df.time.dt.hour.iloc[0])` to replace the first values with the matching hours (since the subtract 0 does nothing). You can define your own rule for the value in `fillna()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply I have a question, If I use data=pd.read_csv('data1') ,  then how to specify this column separately?  According to your code it just read X3 only. But I need this X1,X2 values also for my procedure code.

Comment: Have you tried on your `csv` ? The code doesn't remove `X1` or `X2` if they exist. Have a look at the update where I add random values for `X1` and `X2`

Comment: @ Alexandre B I got an error" initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame" while using StringIO,   python library is "from io import StringIO"

Comment: @team I suspect you're passing a dataframe to `StringIO`. In the answer, I used `StringIO` to create a dataframe from a string. This is just for the example. However, If you want to read `.csv` file, just use `df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file_name')`. Have a look at [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Using this, you can start the code from my answer at `df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: @ Alexandre B.  Yes I tried your code without using StringIO. But there is another issue that when I code df=df[df['X3]!=0 , when print(df) , length is less . means assume that I have data 120 line. Then when I writ this code length is less, I just want to keep my oher inputs X1,X2 in same length and just change X3  Is there any code to ignore 0 value and then find the time difference?

Comment: In this case, [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with help you. The update uses it. Oups, a moment, The update is wrong

Comment: @ Alexandre B Yes I tried it. Thank you very much. But I have other question. Assume here my X3 is starting time is 7:00:00 I want to put that time 0 and then count the time difference. means (7:00:00 -9:00:00 from starting time=0 then time difference is 2hours). Then what should I have to change in my code.

Comment: The update should answer. Feel free to open new questions instead of expending this one.

Comment: B yes I will ask the new question.

Comment: fIrst of all Thank you for the great answer. When I add your code I got time difference with minus , Why it is coming like that? I upload the image of that

Comment: Glad to help you. I suspect you're comparing time from different dates ?

Comment: yes it is different dates. I collected data till to 7 days. starting 2018/8/6 to 2018 /8/13. Then how I can change the code?

Comment: @ Alexandre B. Each and new day I want to put the start time as 0

Comment: @ Alexandre B. I asked the new question here is the link. Can you look at this question please.                               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518931/how-to-put-the-every-start-time-as-0-in-every-day-for-specific-column-input-data