# How to put the every start time as 0 in every day for specific column input data using panda python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

This question is related to this question

[How to get time difference in specifc rows include in one column data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507531/how-to-get-time-difference-in-specifc-rows-include-in-one-column-data-using-pyth/57507722?noredirect=1#comment101484653_57507722)

Here I have three inputsX1,X2,X3. So here I want to find time difference only X3 inputs.

Code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)


df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%H:%M:%S")
df = df[df['X3'] != 0]
values_others_rows = np.NaN

sub_df = df[df.X3 != 0]
out_values = (sub_df.time.dt.hour - sub_df.shift().time.dt.hour) \
        .to_frame() \
        .fillna(sub_df.time.dt.hour.iloc[0]) \
        .rename(columns={'time': 'out'})  # Rename column
print(out_values)

df = df.join(out_values)                # Add out values
print(df)
```

When I use this code came time difference but with minus value. Because I have different days values.

I got the value with minus :

[image]

As a example:

```html
date      time          x3
10/3/2018 6:00:00     0
10/3/2018 7:00:00     2      start time =0
10/3/2018 8:00:00     0                 time difference=2
10/3/2018 9:00:00     50     first time =9:00:00
10/3/2018 10:00:00    0            :
10/3/2018 11:00:00    0            :
10/3/2018 12:00:00    0            :
10/3/2018 13:45:00    0
10/3/2018 15:00:00    0
10/3/2018 16:00:00    0
10/3/2018 17:00:00    0
10/3/2018 18:00:00    0
10/3/2018 19:00:00    20
10/3/2018 20:00:00    0
10/4/2018 6:00:00     50     new day : start time=0  
10/4/2018 7:00:00     50     first time: 7:00:00   time difference=1
10/4/2018 8:00:00     0             
10/4/2018 9:00:00     0
10/4/2018 11:00:00    10     second time: 11:00:00  time difference=4
10/4/2018 12:00:00    20
10/4/2018 13:00:00    50
```

So I want to write this in my code. But I don't know how to write this. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

My csv file :
[CSV file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

After using new code nothing display of time difference

[image: data['new']

After print(df)

When I used the jezrael  code again the minus value is showing:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

df1 = df[df.X3!= 0]

df['new'] = df1['time'].dt.minute.groupby(df1['date']).diff()
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Image of data['new']

[image]

But my expected time difference is:

```html
date      time          x3    time_difference
10/3/2018 6:00:00     0           -
10/3/2018 7:00:00     2          start_time=0  
10/3/2018 8:00:00     0            
10/3/2018 9:00:00     50          2hr
10/3/2018 10:00:00    0           
10/3/2018 11:00:00    0            
10/3/2018 12:00:00    0           
10/3/2018 13:45:00    0
10/3/2018 15:00:00    0
10/3/2018 16:00:00    0
10/3/2018 17:00:00    0
10/3/2018 18:00:00    0
10/3/2018 19:00:00    20          12hr from starting time
10/3/2018 20:00:00    0
10/4/2018 6:00:00     50          start_time=0   
10/4/2018 7:00:00     50            1hr 
10/4/2018 8:00:00     0             
10/4/2018 9:00:00     0
10/4/2018 11:00:00    10          5hr
10/4/2018 12:00:00    20          6hr
10/4/2018 13:00:00    0
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what is expected output, can you add new column to your sample data for check my solution?

Comment: @ jezrael  yes checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows by condition and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for difference, last replace missing values by `0`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data6 - data6.csv')
#print (df)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%H:%M:%S")

df1 = df[df.x3 != 0]

df['new'] = df1['time'].dt.hour.groupby(df1['date']).diff()
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df.head(20))
         date                time   x1  x2  x3  new
0   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 06:00:00   63   0   0    0
1   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 07:00:00   63   0   2    0
2   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 08:00:00  104  11   0    0
3   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 09:00:00   93   0  50    2
4   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 10:00:00  177   0   0    0
5   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 11:00:00  133   0   0    0
6   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 12:00:00   70   0   0    0
7   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 13:45:00   83   0   0    0
8   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 15:00:00  127   0   0    0
9   10/3/2018 1900-01-01 16:00:00  205   0   0    0
10  10/3/2018 1900-01-01 17:00:00  298   0   0    0
11  10/3/2018 1900-01-01 18:00:00  234   0   0    0
12  10/3/2018 1900-01-01 19:00:00  148   0  20   10
13  10/3/2018 1900-01-01 20:00:00  135   0   0    0
14  10/3/2018 1900-01-01 21:30:00  100   0  50    2
15  10/4/2018 1900-01-01 06:00:00  166   0   0    0
16  10/4/2018 1900-01-01 07:00:00   60   0   0    0
17  10/4/2018 1900-01-01 08:00:00  120  10  10    0
18  10/4/2018 1900-01-01 09:00:00   80  40  20    1
19  10/4/2018 1900-01-01 11:00:00   60  70  50    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. When I used your code one problem is coming that length is reducing. But I want is keeping the same length of X1,X2 and X3 and finding the time difference of X3 input value.

Comment: @team - reducing? Hmmm, do you correct assign `df1` and `df`? Because in my solution is no reducion, because assign filtered values `df1` to column in `df` - in code `df['new'] = df1['time'].dt.hour.groupby(df1['date']).diff()`

Comment: @ jezrael  After changing the code length is okay, but no time difference values are showing. I pasted the image of data['new']

Comment: @ jezrael  Can we put this as minute not in hour, I guess it will be easy , isn't it?

Comment: @team - `Can we put this as minute not in hour` - do you think change `.hour` to `.minute` ? Not understand. Btw, tested your smple data and seems working nice

Comment: @ jezrael  yes converting .hour to .minute, But why mine is coming no values. here why did you put like this "data6 - data6.csv'" it should be like "data6.csv" isn't it

Comment: hay I found the error, why is it coming like that, here first I combine date and time together and tried to display the difference of time , then again coming minus  value, Because of date. In your code you just use time only and came with "1900-01-01" instead of that I want to find the time difference with combination of date and time , I rewrite the code and paste the image of data['new']

Comment: @team - I dont understand, is possible add excepted output to values with seen also another columns? my solution not working? Or yes?

Comment: Here I upload the what I expected for time_diffrence. Your code helpful to me change some part of my code. But still minus values are displaying .

Comment: @team - hmm, so you need `df['new'] = df1.groupby('date')['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds() // 3600` instead `df['new'] = df1['time'].dt.minute.groupby(df1['date']).diff()` ?

Comment: Absolutely. It worked. Your code is now absolutely works for me. and I apologies from you , because I guess some of my question didn't clear for you. So once again Thank you for helping me.